# Android : two url link execute at a same time using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am try to execute two urls using AsyncTask to get somedata at a same time. But in both of them only one exceute at a same time. how i solve it.
both url have tag value. using tag value i gets data from the url.

```
public class Manager extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner  area_wise_sp,
            lineman_wise_sp;

    ProgressBar pbar;

    List<NameValuePair> params;
    String url_add_cus = "http://10.0.2.2/api/android/add_cab.php";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.money_manager);



        pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
         params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // execute two url with different tag value 

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "area_list"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("opId", saveOpid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", saveCompany));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), params.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new ReadJSONResult().execute(url_add_cus);

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "pack_list"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("opId", saveOpid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", saveCompany));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), params.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new ReadJSONResult().execute(url_add_cus);
            }
        }

    }


    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {

                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "failed json",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    class ReadJSONResult extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                Dialog d = new Dialog(MoneyManager.this);
                d.setTitle("result");
                TextView tv = new TextView(MoneyManager.this);
                tv.setText(result.toString());
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if ("pack_list".matches((jsonObject.getString("tag")))) {
                    // listval_for_pack.clear();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "packlist done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } else if ("area_list".matches((jsonObject.getString("tag")))) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "arealist done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use only one Asynctask, execute one request after the other and then combine the data togheter

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic. I have modified it. Hope it will help you.

```
// in onPostExecute

else if ("area_list".matches((jsonObject.getString("tag")))) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "arealist done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "pack_list"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("opId", saveOpid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", saveCompany));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), params.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new ReadJSONResult().execute(url_add_cus);
                    }
```